# Detect when other process is shutdown OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, process, process-management

I need a way to determine from a Cocoa app if a given process name is running.  One idea I had was to use NSTask and poll using ps aux | grep processName.  Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to easily adapt this sample code to look for a process by name:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/PIDFromBSDProcessName/listing1.html

Comment: Thanks!! I will check this out.  Knew there had to be a better way :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Snow Leopard, you could take a look at the [NSRunningApplication](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008799-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) class particularly the [+ runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSRunningApplication/runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:) method

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [`GetBSDProcessList()` function](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1123.html) quite successfully several times.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check that a process is running for a duration (rather than at an instant), take a look at [Tech Note 2050: Observing Process Lifetimes Without Polling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2050). Some of the techniques in the tech note have [limitations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2050/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003081-CH1-SECTION12): they only let you monitor GUI processes in the current login session. [kqueues](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2050/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003081-CH1-SUBSECTION10), however, might be exactly what you're looking for: they let you monitor one process of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Process Manager](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html) API to loop through all the running processes with [GetNextProcess](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GetNextProcess) and use [CopyProcessName](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CopyProcessName) to get the name of the process. Note that this technique does not solve the problem of observing when a process is launched.